# Record Hover in Selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Is there a way to record mouse hover effect in selenium ide?

I have already tried mouse Over command that doesn't returns the expected effects

Comment: I'm unsure if this is possible using the selenium ide, however you could do it in webdriver using selenium Actions like so `new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(element).Perform();`

Comment: @Dillanm Yes when I tried it on webdriver it successfully perform the hovering effect but I want it to be done through ide. When there is a command "mouseOver" to hover an element then it must show the effects. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Have you tried putting a pause after the mouseOver command? This will let you see whether or not the button is actually being hovered over as it might otherwise be instantaneous.

Could you also maybe provide some HTML or a screenshot of the element you're working with.

Comment: Yes I tried pause command but no change. Actually functionality is that on hovering a main menu, submenu appears. Website Link: http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/section/concerts?tm_link=tm_homeA_music_header 

Here is the screenshot for commands I tried:  http://prntscr.com/dxm78o